# jQuery addclass and toggle class not setting my class

Tags: jquery, css

Good Day

For some reason the browser is ignoring my addClass and toggleClass jquery calls:

#### HTML

```
<div id="menuNav" class="row-fluid">
    <div id="menuNavSub" class="span12">
        <ul>                         
            <li id="homeNav"><a href="index.aspx"><img src="images/homeNav2.png" /></a></li>
            <li id="galleryNav"><a href="galleries.aspx" class="block"><img src="images/homeNav2.png" /></a></li>
            <li id="aboutNav"><a href="about.aspx"><img src="images/homeNav2.png" /></a></li>               
            <li id="contactNav"><a href="contact.aspx"><img src="images/homeNav2.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>              
    </div>         
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.activeNavHome1 {
    background-position: -200px center;
}

.activeNavHome2{
    background: url('/images/homeNavSmall.png') no-repeat left center;
    background-position: -150px center;
}
```

#### jQuery:

```
    $('#homeNav').addClass('activeNavHome1');

    if ($(window).width() < 1080) {
       $('#homeNav').toggleClass('activeNavHome2');
     }
```

NOTES: I am using `ASP.NET` and the jQuery code is contained in my `index.aspx` file. The HTML is contained with in my master file.

However, when I use

```
$('#homeNav').css('background-position', '-200px center')
```

It works. Why is it not assigning my classes with the `addClass` and `toggleclass` commands? I have made no spelling mistakes in my CSS.

Comment: Are you calling it on ready .....?

Comment: Why is the id in your javascript `homeNav` when it seems to be `menuNav`in your markup?

Comment: If you're using master page why are you not adding it in the masterpage rather than index.aspx?

Comment: check your script in firebug.. make sure if the class is added or not....

Comment: Well your jQuery code works, class activeNavHome1 is added always and activeNavHome2 only when window width < 1080. How and when do you call that code?

Comment: @DextrousDave: Your code is working perfectly fine. You need to post the full code inside which you are calling the above bunch of code, for better analysis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass two classes instead and `i think you didn't referenced a jQuery library` or may be your `doc ready` is missing:

```
<script>
  $(function(){ // <-----------------------------you are missing this
     $('#homeNav').addClass('activeNavHome1');
     if ($(window).width() < 1080) {
       $('#homeNav').toggleClass('activeNavHome1 activeNavHome2');
     }
   });
 </script>
```

### note:

Make sure that you have loaded jQuery before this script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Jai - I have referenced jquery correctly and it is in a document ready function. All my others scripts are working....Any other ideas?